# react-native picker using android styles.xml for change font-family not changed

Tags: android, react-native

i want style font-size and font-family on react-native picker. i already set custom my style on native android. but after my build apk again not change it's still same font.

my code on style.xml

```
<resources>
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
     <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
     <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
 </style>
 <style name="SpinnerItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">>
   <item name="android:fontFamily">CenturyGothicBold</item>
   <item name="android:textSize">16dp</item>
 </style>
</resources>
```

[Already set add new font on asset with react-native link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77PDD.png)

[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDbpe.png)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```html
 TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);

   Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),  "fonts/CenturyGothicBold.ttf");

   tx.setTypeface(custom_font);
```

Or

```html
 AssetManager am = context.getApplicationContext().getAssets();

    typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(am,
            String.format(Locale.US, "fonts/%s", "CenturyGothicBold.ttf"));

    setTypeface(typeface);
```